# How do I Divide Values in a Column by the Value in the Last Cell?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

So I am working in R, and I am trying to write a function. But I reached a roadblock.

I have the following df:

| Number | Freq | CumFreq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00.1 | 2 | 2 |
| 00.5 | 1 | 3 |

...so on and so forth.

I'd like to have it so the numbers in df$CumFreq are divided by the last cell in the df$CumFreq, and create a new column. For instance:

| Number | Freq | CumFreq | CF/n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00.1 | 2 | 2 | 0.667 |
| 00.5 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

Any advice on how to write this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df$CFn <- with(df,CumFreq/sum(Freq))
```

or

```
df$CFn <- with(df,CumFreq/tail(CumFreq,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` approach using `mutate`:

```
df %>% mutate("CF/n" = CumFreq/sum(Freq))

  Number Freq CumFreq      CF/n
1   00.1    2       2 0.6666667
2   00.5    1       3 1.0000000
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of doing it this way?

Comment: In this case, since your question is not that complicated, there might not be advantage of using `dplyr` approach. But in general, `dplyr` is a package designed to handle common data manipulation, and the syntax is usually more "human readable" (i.e. you usually know it's function by the function's name) compared to base R. And also it could be more efficient in processing dataframe that base R.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @Noob3000 If you're looking for efficiency, `data.table` would probably be the number one pick.